# powershell embedding one variable in another one

Tags: variables, powershell

In powershell , for a complicated reason an application needs a 6 character string as a sort of handle (Eg: abcdef) for a long asynchronous operation. I perform this using

```
$replaceHandle = "abcdef"
start-Job -handle $replaceHandle
```

The application stores the status of the asynchronous job in $abcdef (Prefixes string with $)
and i can access parameters of job Status at any time by requesting

```
Get-Status -ID $abcdef.ID
```

Problem for me in my code is i am not able to get this $abcdef.ID properly
I have tried
$($jobVar.ToString()).ID - this gives blank/errors out
maipulating $$jobVar.ID actually gives $'abcdef'.ID

How do i manage to get value of ($abcdef.ID) appropriately ?

Answer (score 2):

It because $jobVar is first interpreted :

try :

```
write-host "the value is $($jobVar.ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

(Get-Variable $b -ValueOnly).Id

This worked