# How can i use powershell embedded parameters?

Tags: variables, powershell

$b = "a00000"

Now due to a complicated application, i want to access $a00000.ID
The application stores a return object inside a variablename (which is a string value of another)

When i try "$b" it shows the value, but $"$b".ID is an error
${$b}.ID is also an error
$'"$b"'.ID is also an error

How do i access value of $a00000.ID given that previously $b=a00000 ?
(one variable name is assigned by a previous string value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell embedding one variable in another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968837/powershell-embedding-one-variable-in-another-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(Get-Variable $b -ValueOnly).Id
```